# replace NAs with previous or following values for big dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a df with 1500 obs. and more then 600 variables. There are a lot of NAs in the df and I found no solution so far to replace them. I would like the NAs to take the previous value. If there is no previous value, the following value should be taken.

I have already tried out a few solutions like `na.locf` etc unfortunately without success. I have a solution that works with the mean. I just can't get it rewritten in a way that solve my problem.

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
  df[is.na(df[,i]), i] <- mean(df[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Maybe someone here has already worked with it and can help me.

Here is an example:

```
            Share1 Share2  Share3 Share4 Share5
2016-01-04 49.5010 21.640 90.0100 93.676     NA
2016-01-05 49.7855 21.987 88.5695 92.329 82.459
2016-01-06 49.0595     NA 87.4735 88.601 81.432
2016-01-07 47.7785     NA 82.8735 83.725 78.934
2016-01-08 47.7435 20.260 82.9275 82.609 79.000
2016-01-09      NA 20.380 83.0530 83.503     NA
2016-01-10 47.7770 20.475 82.9860 83.325 79.645
2016-01-11 48.8095 20.844 83.0320 83.513 78.672
2016-01-12 48.9545     NA 83.7325 85.732 81.090
2016-01-13 48.0195 20.464 82.6305 81.151 81.178
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R "idiomatic" way would be to use `lapply` to do what you ask:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE))
df
#             Share1 Share2  Share3 Share4 Share5
# 2016-01-04 49.5010 21.640 90.0100 93.676 82.459
# 2016-01-05 49.7855 21.987 88.5695 92.329 82.459
# 2016-01-06 49.0595 21.987 87.4735 88.601 81.432
# 2016-01-07 47.7785 21.987 82.8735 83.725 78.934
# 2016-01-08 47.7435 20.260 82.9275 82.609 79.000
# 2016-01-09 47.7435 20.380 83.0530 83.503 79.000
# 2016-01-10 47.7770 20.475 82.9860 83.325 79.645
# 2016-01-11 48.8095 20.844 83.0320 83.513 78.672
# 2016-01-12 48.9545 20.844 83.7325 85.732 81.090
# 2016-01-13 48.0195 20.464 82.6305 81.151 81.178
```

The inner `zoo::na.locf` requires `na.rm=FALSE`, because without it `Share5` will have its first element stripped:

```r
lengths(lapply(df, zoo::na.locf))
# Share1 Share2 Share3 Share4 Share5 
#     10     10     10     10      9 
lengths(lapply(df, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
# Share1 Share2 Share3 Share4 Share5 
#     10     10     10     10     10
```

If you're more comfortable with a `for` loop, then perhaps

```r
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[[i]] <- zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(df[[i]], na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE)
}
```

(Realize that `seq_along(df)` is effectively the same as `seq_len(ncol(df))`.)

As @G.Grothendieck just reminded me, `zoo:::na.locf` has a method that works on whole frames, so the above can be reduced to

```r
na.locf(na.locf(df, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: na.locf(na.locf(df, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast = TRUE)

Comment: Or `data.table::setnafill`: `setnafill(setnafill(d, type = "locf"), type = "nocb")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `fill` function from `tidyr` package specifying the argument `.direction` to be `.direction = "downup"`. To apply the function to all columns at once you can specify the the columns to be a tidy-selector `everything()`, which selects all columns from the current selection context.

So, in your case it would be

```
df <- fill(df, everything(), .direction = "downup")
```

To learn more about `fill` function visit [this](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) and to learn more about `everything()` function visit [that](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/everything.html).